# i have 350 chevy the crackshaft and the camshaft are not in time with each other and the engine is assy and the car what can i do to find tdc

Tags: valve-timing

crankshaft and camshaft are not in time with each other and the engine is in the car crankshaft was moved with out timing chain on what I do to get them in time with each other

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How do you know it's out of time if you don't know how to time the engine (or find TDC on cyl #1)? What was done to the engine which required the cam chain/gears to be taken off?

Comment: Base timing can easily be set with the notches and witness marks on the crank pulley, timing cover, cam gears, etc.  I'd post a picture, but there are 4 million variations of "Chevy 350" so I'd need to know the specific engine  you are referring to.  Is it a stock motor?  What is the year and model of the vehicle?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 probably has 3 special variations in his garage that aren't even included in my 4 million estimate . . .  A